# How can I debug Python code without running a script (using Eclipse)?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, aptana

I've noticed how easy it is to debug a Python script from Eclipse. Simply set breakpoints and run a Python script from the debug menu. But is it possible to start a Python Interactive Interpreter instead of running a particular Python script, whilst still having Eclipse breaking on breakpoints? This would make it **so** much easier to test functions.

Thanks for any help

---

Still looking for a simple/ish way to start the debugger in Eclipse->PyDev that lets me use the interactive debugger. None of the answers as of yet is acceptable

Comment: I'm not sure about eclipse, but vanilla `pdb` can do that.

Comment: Did you use vanilla as an adjective there?

Comment: Yes. `python -m pdb ...` is what I meant.

Comment: Cool. I still want this in Eclipse though :-)

Comment: I do it in Vim. Maybe you can switch to Vim? ;-)

Comment: @Keith: As a matter of fact I've just started using Vim for development. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @codemonkey The quick answer is to please take a look at my [vim-python integration package](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fvim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this, in the script, you can write a function, say onlyForTest, then each time you write a new function and want to test it, you can just put it in the onlyForTest function, then specify some arguments required by the new function you just write, then open the interactive python shell, import the script, call the onlyForTest function, check out the result.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now :) I really would prefer to use the interactive interpreter though.

Comment: Alas, in the lack of a better answer, I'm marking this one as correct seeing as it's what I'm stuck doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly write code to setup a breakpoint in your script, and then "remote debug". That means having pydevd in the pythonpath of your script wherever it is running, and running the eclipse pydev remote debugger on your devbox. If it's all happening on the same machine, this is fairly straightforward.
If not, you'll need to specify the hostname of the dev machine running the python remote debugger in the call to settrace(). You'll also need pydevd available on the machine running the script.

I have got this working in the past without having to install eclipse+pydevd on the machine running the script. It's not totally straightforward, and if you go that route I'd recommend checking that the pydevd versions match or at least you know they're compatible. Otherwise you end up wasting time debugging the debugger.

For details see: [Pydev Remote Debugger](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html)

Comment: I have to say, I've read through your post and link, and I can't see how your answer has anything to do with my question :P I just want to set breakpoints in PyDev and start the interactive interpreter